# Java skips some of my code after for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods

I am trying to get the union of two sets but for some reason my code has no errors but my method for getting the union skips some of the code

```
    public Set union(Set s){
    Set union = new Set(count+s.count);

    for(int x=0;x<count;x++)
        union.set[x] = set[x];

    for(int y=count;y<s.count;y++){
        union.set[y] = s.set[y];
    }
    return union;
}
```

The program works but the problem is after the first loop it skips the rest of the code inside the method.

Here's the rest of my code that might be related to the problem

```
public class Set implements InterfaceSet{
private int set[];
private int count;

public Set(){
        set = new int[max];
        count = 0;
    }

public Set(int size){
    set = new int[size];
    count = size;
}

private int found;
public void add(int e){
    found = 0;
    if(count<10){
        for(int x: set){
            if(x==e){
                found=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found==0){
            set[count] = e;
            count++;
        }
    }
}

public void display( ){
    for(int x=0;x < count; x++){
        System.out.println(set[x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your union methods seems incorrect.
Could you try this?

```java
public Set union(Set s){
    Set union = new Set(count + s.count);

    for(int x = 0; x < count; x++)
        union.set[x] = set[x];

    // updated
    for(int y = 0; y < s.count; y++){
        union.set[count + y] = s.set[y];
    }

    return union;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the second loop, `count` will be equal to the size of the first set, but you're comparing it to the size of the second set.  If the first set is the same size as or larger than the second set, then the condition `count < s.count` will be false, skipping the loop.

You need to use a different indexing variable for where you're inserting and where you're reading:

```
public Set union(Set s){
    Set union = new Set(count+s.count);
    int insertPoint = 0; 
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++, insertPoint++) {
        union.set[insertPoint] = set[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<s.count; i++, insertPoint++) {
        union.set[insertPoint] = s.set[i];
    }
    return union;
}
```

It's also generally convention to use `i`, `j`, `k`, for indexing variables unless they have some specific meaning, so I went ahead and switched `x` and `y` to `i`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. It really helps a lot. the code works now :)))